Why isn't into_iter move the value when called on reference
Consider the following example:
fn print_ref(vec: &mut Vec<String>) {
    vec.into_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v));
    vec.into_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v)); //ok, why is it compiled fine?
}

fn print(vec: Vec<String>) {
    vec.into_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v));
    vec.into_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v)); //error: use of moved value
}

Playground
The problem I see that iterator implementation for reference looks as:
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<'a, T, A: Allocator> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T, A> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    type IntoIter = slice::IterMut<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter_mut()
    }
}

So my understanding was that calling into_iter on &mut Vec<String> should move the reference essentially prohibiting further usage of it.
Why is the second vec.into_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v)); in the example above still succeeds?

Because of reborrows.
